# Close the lid of unsealed jar with pop-up lid

Tags: storage-lifetime, cheese, refrigerator

I bought a cheese spread bottle last night and I opened it today. It said in the bottle to refrigerate after opening, it came with a pop up lid.

I don't have the facility to use a refrigerator. How long it can be fresh without refrigerating and can I able to seal it back if yes how?

Comment: Technically it won't be safe after more than a few hours at room temperature. No, you can't seal it again.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall few hours mean, can it be 7-8 hours?

Comment: Nope, more like 2-3.

Comment: Is there any way to keep it safe for the time I mentioned? :-/

Comment: It would probably stay safe if you keep it above 140 °F/60 °C all day.

Comment: @amarillo isn't above 60 °C too hot? I'm sorry if i'm worng. RT in our country is 34-37 °C and its too hot

Comment: Well, it’s much too hot for an outdoor air temperature, yes. But they say that foods are safe if you keep them above 60 °C, because bacteria doesn’t grow very well when it’s that hot. That won’t help you unless you have some way of keeping your food hot all day long though. That temperature also might slowly cook the food. If you don’t have a refrigerator or freezer, or some way to heat the food up and keep it that way, it might go bad.

Comment: @amarillo Thanks for the explanation, now I got the point

Comment: You may just have to throw a cheese spread party. :-/ Find a lot of crackers and a couple dozen friends?

Comment: Actually, I bought it for my home and I was not aware about the refrigerating warning, I opened it. Now, I've kept it in the refrigerator. But, I have to travel 6 hours for my home, tomorrow. That is the problem now :(

Comment: Can you keep it on ice somehow? A cooler with ice should be enough for six hours.

Comment: @amarillo Thanks for the suggestion. I can make it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours it will be unsafe if it was below 140 °F/60 °C during that time.

Even if you resealed it, it wouldn't "undo" the bacterial growth that occurred during the time it was unsealed.  So, no, it would not be safe to do this even if you could.